# About combining the video with different framerates using opencl and c++

Tags: c++, opencl

this is my first question on stack overflow. I am doing research on my thesis. I need a help on how to combine two videos with different frame rates? Can anybody give me some suggestions? Anything from anybody will be helpful. I am also doing research on it but a references would be much appreciated from anybody in stack overflow.

Comment: Did you try interpolation between two frames(or some other derivate based approximation) to blend an imaginary mid-frame with other video's exact frame? (getting output with one video, interpolating other video to blend) there are some motion estimation algorithms too(again using derivatives)

Comment: I been searching for help not yet tried but want to implement as soon as possible if i find any references.